# Is there a way to create a button within a canvas for my game?

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm, tkinter-canvas

I have made a very basic pong game, but when the ball hits the bottom, I've only set for everything to stop moving. Is there a way to create a button within the canvas that says, for example, "PLAY AGAIN" and when I click it, game starts again. I will also need a button at the beginning for starting the game.

I've tried to create a button to pop up when the ball hits the bottom of the canvas, but that hasn't worked. I looked this up and couldn't really find anything that answered my question.

```
from tkinter import*
import random
import time

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.paddle = paddle
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10,10,25,25, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
        starts = [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
        random.shuffle(starts)
        self.x = starts[0]
        self.y = -3
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.hit_bottom = False


    def hit_paddle(self, pos):
        paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
        if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
                return True
    return False


    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1] <= 0:
            self.y = 3
        if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
            self.hit_bottom = True
        if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
            self.y = -3
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 3
        if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = -3



class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 10, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 200, 300)
        self.x = 0
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>',self.turn_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right)


    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 0
        elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = 0


    def turn_left(self, evt):
        self. x = -3


    def turn_right(self, evt):
        self.x = 3


tk = Tk()
tk.title("Game")
tk.resizable(0,0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost",1)
canvas = Canvas(tk,width=500,height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()



paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'blue')
ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, 'red')

while 1:
    if ball.hit_bottom == False:
        ball.draw()
        paddle.draw()
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

I don't know how to insert a button within the canvas (to reset the game). Can anyone help pls.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To place a button (or any widget) on a canvas without the canvas to resizing, you should use `.create_window()`

```
button = Button(tk, text="do something", command=do_something)
buttonwindow = canvas.create_window(10, 10, window=button)
```

This will create your button with upper-left corner at (10, 10) relative to the canvas, without resizing the canvas itself.

Another method is using `.place()`

```
button.place(x=1, y=1)
```

This would stick the button in those coordinates, so just match them up to the canvas and you should be fine.